# Identifying Duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to identify duplicate cells in a macro. I'm trying to use macros so I can extract the entire row once the duplicate is identified.

I used this code:

```
Sub MarkDuplicates()
Dim iWarnColor As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant


Set rng = Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Range("D1:D1613") 
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccentz

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    vVal = rngCell.Text
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, vVal) = 1) Then
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

but it only identified empty cells. At the moment I'm trying to only identify duplicate text and I'll extract them later.

Can you please help me do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put `rng.Cells` - the `.Cells` is implied - just use `rng`

(^ This is semantics - do whatever you want)

Instead of checking `rngCell.Text` - try `rngCell.Value`.

`.Text` [is incredibly slow.](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

^ Really, based on this, should probably use `.Value2` instead of `.Value` for maximum speeeeeeed!

Of course, if we are that concerned, we would [use a variant array](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/), but let's keep it simple.

Also, idk why you use `xlThemeColorAccentz` and `ColorIndex`

This may work, but it doesn't work for me - I would just use `RGB`

You're doing a `CountIf` on the range which is sort of meh.

As for checking duplicates,
I would recommend using a [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) for this purpose.

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Your code becomes:

```
Sub MarkDuplicates()
Dim iWarnColor As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set rng = Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Range("D1:D1613")

rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'Optionally clear all coloring
iWarnColor = RGB(230, 180, 180)  'Red

For Each rngCell In rng
    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then 'Ignore blank cells
        If Not dict.Exists(rngCell.Value) Then
            dict.Add rngCell.Value, rngCell.Row 'Store the row if we want
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.Color = iWarnColor
            'Optionally color the original cell:
            'Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Cells(dict(rngCell.Value), "D").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Results with optional coloring:

[image: Results]

**Edit (Not Using Dictionary):**

So, you're using a mac - oh wellz.

I didn't mention it before, but you can use conditional formatting to solve this.

Anyway, let's just use a collection.

A collection works a lot like a dictionary, but we typically have to loop through it to determine if a particular Key/Value pair exists.

We can cheat this by trying to get a value for a key that doesn't exist and catch the error - I added a function to simplify this process.

```
Sub MarkDuplicates()
Dim iWarnColor As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant
Dim Col As New Collection
Set rng = Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Range("D1:D1613")
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
iWarnColor = RGB(230, 180, 180)
For Each rngCell In rng
    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then 'Ignore blank cells
        If Not IsInCollection(Col, rngCell.Value2) Then
            Col.Add rngCell.Row, Key:=rngCell.Value2
        Else
            rngCell.Interior.Color = iWarnColor
            'Optionally color the original cell
            Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Cells(Col(rngCell.Value2), "D").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
Function IsInCollection(Col As Collection, Val As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print (Col(Val))
    IsInCollection = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

New Results (The Same):

[image: Collections]

Comment: FWIW, in the OP's **specific case** there is no difference between `For Each rngCell In rng.Cells` and `For Each rngCell In rng`.  But if `rng` was set as `Set rng = Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Range("D1:D1613").EntireRow` (for instance), there would be a difference - using just `In rng` would set `rngCell` to be each row, while using `In rng.Cells` would set `rngCell` to be each cell.  It is usually safest to always use the `rng.Cells` approach so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work on my MacBook. I get ActiveX error, can you please help?

Comment: @Ameture AFAIK - Microsoft's Scripting Runtime isn't available on Macs, so you won't be able to use a Dictionary.  But I guess that explains the (slightly inappropriate) [macos] tag.  I will edit your tags to say [excel-vba-mac] so that people know you **are** looking for a Mac solution.

Comment: So I added this line `Sheets("WorkSheet").Range("A" & Value2).Value = Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Range("A" & Value2).Value` to get the original line and the duplicate line into a different sheet. I added this code right after this line `Sheets("AllAccounts (12-05-2017)").Cells(Col(rngCell.Value2), "K").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)`, but I get an error. Your code is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary   Drop-in replacement for Scripting.Dictionary on Mac

Comment: Thank you very much! but for my learning purpose, how do I manipulate the code so I can set it to check for duplicates from a different column (i.e. 'K') or to copy more row fields than just A - D?

Comment: Just change your `rng` variable. Honestly, there are probably better ways using temp sheets and just sorting your data while reading through it. Then you just check to see if the row below is the same value (duplicate) - it depends on what you need to do. As for different columns, change the `Offset` and `Resize`. If you'd like, I can go through and comment each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are several ways to do this.  Here is one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:XF" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(1, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```